# How can i filter an array of JSON objects which again contain an array of JSON objects?

Tags: arrays, node.js, json, underscore.js, lodash

I want to get names from the sample json object where workLocation is "city 1" how can i do that?

I know we can filter using underscore or lodash the array of json objects like var filteredData = _.where(jsonData,{"id": 1}) but not sure how to get the name from  specific workLocation?

```
[
{
    "id": 1,
    "name": "John",
    "age": 12,
    "data": [
        {
            "worklocation" : "city 1",
            "pin" : "909"
        },
        {
            "worklocation" : "city 2",
            "pin" : "808"
        }
    ]
},
{
    "id": 2,
    "name": "Shawn",
    "age": 22,
    "data": [
        {
            "worklocation" : "city 3",
            "pin" : "608"
        },
        {
            "worklocation" : "city 4",
            "pin" : "508"
        }
    ]
}
]
```

I expect the output of { "name" : "Shawn"} when i filter using city 3

Answer (score 0):

You have to iterate the two arrays and compare if was possible to find the `worklocation` with the same ID. I created an example for you.

```js
const data = [
  {
    "id": 1,
    "name": "John",
    "age": 12,
    "data": [{
        "worklocation": "city 1",
        "pin": "909"
      },
      {
        "worklocation": "city 2",
        "pin": "808"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "id": 2,
    "name": "Shawn",
    "age": 22,
    "data": [{
        "worklocation": "city 3",
        "pin": "608"
      },
      {
        "worklocation": "city 4",
        "pin": "508"
      }
    ]
  }
]

const findName = (list, id) => {
  const found = list.find(item => {
    const foundCity = item.data.find(worklocationItem => worklocationItem.worklocation === id)
    return !!foundCity
  })
  if (found) {
    return found.name
  }
  return null
}

const el = document.getElementById('data')
const cityID = 'city 3';
el.innerHTML = findName(data, cityID)
console.log(findName(data, cityID))
```

```html
<div id="data"></div>
```